# django print only one value in for loop in template

Tags: python, django, loops, templates

I want to display only one value from for loop in template. 
Let's say I have this:

```
{% for category in categories %}
    {{category.name}}
    <a href="{% url "my_url" category.id %}">See All</a>
{% endfor %}
```

If I have 5 category then See All in being printed 5 times. How can I only print it once..
Thanx in adnvance..

Comment: Why do you need to have 'category.id' in 'See All' link?

Comment: suppose if I want to redirect in another link.. consider it as detail..

Comment: only print it once, but when?

Comment: What should the link point to?

Comment: I just want to print See All once.. Say See All points to any link with category id ?? If I write see all outside the loop I cant access category.id...

Comment: How do you expect the link to point to different categories at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

You should have a main page with all your categories in which you will send it `context['categories']`

And if you don't need to have a link between your categories in detail just send the current category in the views.py :

`context['category']`

**EDIT:**
If all you want to do is break in the loop you can't in django template but you can use `slice` :

`{% for category in categories|slice:":1" %}`

It will just go through the loop **once**

Answer (score 0):

You have to limit the object and send that object to template

```
tempalte_var['content'] = Categories.objects.all()[:5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way but check this:

```
{% for category in categories %}
    {% if categories|length > 1 %}
        <a href="{% url "my_url" category.id %}">See All</a>
    {% else %}
        {{categories[1].name}}
        <a href="{% url "my_url" category.id %}">{{category.name}}</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will print the first element in Category

```
    {% for category in categories %}
        {% if categories | first %}  
            {{category.name}}
            <a href="{% url "my_url" category.id %}">See All</a>
        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
```