# Django print fisrt match value in for loop in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have 3 models, and they are referenced by Foreign Keys, I need to display a report of all OrderDetails data with some filters.

I need to include also, the date of the OrderEntry AND the date of the Inventory entry. But when I try to render the 3 querysets the dates are repeated (n)times.

**How can I limit to print only the first or the last match in the loop?**

models.py

```
class OEntradaDetalle(models.Model):
    oentrada = models.ForeignKey(OEntrada, related_name='orden')
    ...


class RecepcionOEntrada(models.Model):
    oentradadetalle = models.ForeignKey(OEntradaDetalle, related_name='recepciones')
    folio = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ...

class InventarioEntrada(models.Model):
    cantidad = models.DecimalField(default=0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    epc = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, blank=True)
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    oentrada = models.ForeignKey('OEntrada', blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

views.py

```
        detalles = OEntradaDetalle.objects.filter(oentrada=oentrada)
        recibidos = RecepcionOEntrada.objects.filter(oentradadetalle__in=detalles)
        inventario = InventarioEntrada.objects.filter(oentrada=oentrada)
        return render(request, 'reporteOEFolio.html', locals())
```

template reporteOEFolio.html

```
{% for d in detalles %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ d.epc }}</td>
          ...
          <td>{% for r in recibidos %}{% if r.oentradadetalle == d %}}{{ r.fecha|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}</td>
          <td>{% for r in recibidos %}{% if r.oentradadetalle == d %}{{ r.fecha|time:"H:i:s" }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}</td>
          <td>{% for r in recibidos %}{% if r.oentradadetalle == d %}{{ r.folio }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}</td>
          <td>{% for i in inventario %}{% if i.epc == d.epc %}{{ i.fecha|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}</td>
          <td>{% for i in inventario %}{% if i.epc == d.epc %}{{ i.fecha|time:"H:i:s" }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}</td>
        </tr>
    {% empty %}
```

What actually I am trying to do is to print first the data of the OEntradaDetalle object, then with a for loop I am looking for a match and then print the value. BUT if the value is many times in the queryset it prints as many times as it matches.

**Is there any way to print only the first match? like a `break`?**

**Is there any way to print only the last match? like overwriting the value?**

possible but NOT duplicate of:
[django print loop value only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27171379/django-print-loop-value-only-once) or [django print only one value in for loop in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169481/django-print-only-one-value-in-for-loop-in-template)

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible answers to this question. Most simply, you can reference a single item in a queryset thus:

```
qset[0]
```

If your queryset is returning multiple values that are identical, you can compress those down thus:

```
qset.distinct()
```

Last, if you want to iterate over the "many" side of a relationship but reference a single copy of the "one" side, you can use the templatetag regroup to good effect: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup

Comment: I dont need to do this in my view, because i need to show many fields in the template, there can be many values for one entry, and I need a table, not a list, so this is not what I am looking for, thank you anyway.